# db4o - weird characters when retrieving objects

Tags: java, database, db4o

```
import java.io.File;
import com.db4o.Db4o;
import com.db4o.Db4oEmbedded;
import com.db4o.ObjectContainer;
import com.db4o.ObjectSet;
import com.db4o.query.Query;

public class Student {

private String name;

public AlumnoBDOO(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ObjectContainer bd = Db4oEmbedded.openFile("students.db4o");
    try {

        Student s1 = new Student("Carl");
        bd.store(s1)
        showStudents(bd);

       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } finally {
           bd.close();
       }
    }

public static void showResult(ObjectSet rs){
    System.out.println("Retrieved "+rs.size()+" objects");
    while(rs.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(rs.next());
    }
}

public static void showStudents(ObjectContainer bd){
    Query query = bd.query();
    query.constrain(Student.class);
    query.descend("name");
    ObjectSet rs = query.execute();
    showResult(rs);
}

}
```

I just simply want to store a Student in the db4o database but when I want to retrieve all of them it outputs like this:

```
Student@61070a02
```

I'm using Eclipse Juno and db40 v.8.0 which I already added as external jar.
Why am I getting those weird characters instead of "Carl"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not weired, but the default implementation of the [toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) method. To get meaningfull information you should override this method in your Student class.

Comment: Oh thanks. I already tried the toString method but directly in the printing line, not implementing it as method :)